# What is the difference between transform & transform_df in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

Can someone explain why we need `transform` & `transform_df` methods separately?

Answer (score 9):

There's a small difference between the `@transform` and `@transform_df` decorators in Code Repositories:

- `@transform_df` operates exclusively on `DataFrame` objects.
- `@transform` operates on `transforms.api.TransformInput` and `transforms.api.TransformOutput` objects rather than `DataFrame`s.

If your data transformation depends exclusively on `DataFrame` objects, you can use the `@transform_df()` decorator. This decorator injects `DataFrame` objects and expects the compute function to return a DataFrame.

Alternatively, you can use the more general `@transform()` decorator and explicitly call the `dataframe()` method to access a `DataFrame` containing your input dataset.

Answer (score 2):

One addition to the answer of @Adil B.
`@transform_df` can handle only one output, whereas in @transform can have multiple, but you are in chagre of writing the output:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

@transform_df(
    Output("some_foundry_id"),
    input_dataset=Input("another_foundy_id"),
)
def compute(input_dataset: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    return input_dataset
```

the dataframe you return here will be saved by palantir in the output

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output

@transform(
    input_1=Input("..."),
    output_1=Output("..."),
    output_2=Output("..."),
)
def compute(input_1: Input, output_1: Output, output_2: Output) -> None:
    output_1.write_dataframe(input_1.dataframe())
    output_2.write_dataframe(input_1.dataframe())
```